# How to turn off HTTP compression for downloaded zip files?

Tags: asp.net, http, compression, zip

I have an ASP.NET web application that has HTTP compression enabled (through IIS settings). One of the features of the app involves creating multiple text files and packaging them as a single zip file to be downloaded by the user.

With HTTP compression enabled, the files created by the application are zipped twice - once by the web application and once more by HTTP compression; with the result that when the user downloads the zip file, it has 1 file which is the application generated zip file, and this second zip file has the original contents.

My requirement is to disable HTTP compression only for the zip file. How do I achieve this? The file extension "zip" is not included in the metabase file for compression.

Comment: Are you sure that you've seen this behavior? HTTP compression is usually [zlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib), _not_ [Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)). And I can't imagine that enough people would want an automatic Zip-file creation that MS would implement it in their server. But zlib compression is quite useful for lower-bandwidth clients, so it is implemented nearly everywhere. You're right that double-compression is nearly useless, but it should not be a bother to users, perhaps just a 1% transfer size increase.

Comment: I've used Gzip compression on the web site through IIS settings. And creating a zip file is one feature of the web application - users generate some content that are created as separate txt files, and zipped into a single archive. Issue is when they try to download this archive when IIS compression is turned on - they need to unzip the file twice. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found what the issue is: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841120

Though this article says Sharepoint, the same solution is applicable in my case also. I fixed it by changing the MIME type to "application/octet-stream" instead of "application/x-zip-compressed" in my code (since I'm generating the zip file on the fly). That seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

1.Disable global static compression by executing the following command at a command prompt:
adsutil set w3svc/filters/compression/parameters/HcDoStaticCompression false

Look into the site for above mentioned details as these are extracted from:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/502ef631-3695-4616-b268-cbe7cf1351ce.mspx?mfr=true

Also look into http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloc/archive/2008/12/31/how-to-disable-http-compression-for-specific-file-types.aspx .

This may help

Comment: The zip files are created on the fly, so I doubt turning off static compression will help. I'm doing pretty much what the last paragraph of the article in the second link talks about - creating content in memory and streaming it to the client.